# Accessing associative array by object

Tags: php, php-8.1

It's possible to access associative array by object? I tried to use `__toString` method, but it isn't automatically called.

```
class ColumnItem {
  private string $name;
  
  public function __construct(string $name) {
    $this->name = $name;
  }
  
  public function __toString() {
    return $this->name;
  }
}

...

$array = ['Name' => 'John'];
$nameItem = new ColumnItem('Name');
//$name = $array[$nameItem]; // PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Illegal offset type
$name = $array[strval($nameItem)];
```

Comment: It's called when you _cast_ an object to string (which isn't always done implicitly)

Comment: This would work in older versions of PHP, though you'd get a warning. One of the backward incompatible changes in PHP 8 was elevating that warning to an error exception. Now you have to convert it to a string, one way or another. If you want to avoid using strval, you can trigger the string conversion with `$name = $array["$nameItem"];`

Comment: Why not call __toString method directly? `$name = $array[$nameItem->__toString()];`

Comment: If your question is really "Is it possible to index an associative array by object", the answer is no, however you can use [`SplObjectStorage`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php) if you actually have that need.